# Current date as example in Springfox & Swagger-UI

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

With SpringFox 2.9.2, how can I set the example for a `LocalDate` field to be the current date?

Some examples of things I've attempted:

## 1) LocalDate field, no example value

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Request {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Reservation date as YYYY-MM-DD", required = true)
    @NotNull
    public LocalDate date;
}
```

This shows the following example in `swagger-ui.html`:

```
{
  "date": "string"
}
```

## 2) LocalDate field, example value

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Request {
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2019-05-29", notes = "Reservation date as YYYY-MM-DD", required = true)
    @NotNull
    public LocalDate date;
}
```

This shows the following example in `swagger-ui.html`:

```
{
  "date": "2019-05-29"
}
```

Format-wise this is exactly what I'm looking for, but will still display the same value tomorrow (instead of "2019-05-30").

## 3) LocalDateTime field, no example value

```java
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Request {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Reservation date as YYYY-MM-DD", required = true)
    @NotNull
    public LocalDateTime date;
}
```

This shows the following example in `swagger-ui.html`:

```
{
  "date": "2019-05-29T06:28:31.382Z"
}
```

Again otherwise exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't want the time part `T06:28:31.382Z`.

Comment: It is more about jackson serializer for LocalDate, may not be related to SpringFox

Comment: I do not think, it is possible with current springfox, however, there is an attribute call extension for ApiModelProperty, you can explore on that.

Comment: Asked this now also on https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3010